# pip installed non specified generator_tools package and fired `AssertionError: Python version 2.5 or 2.6 required` error

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I'm working on python2.7 under virtual env, I tried to install a project which works perfectly in prod server, with this requirements :

```
Django==1.3
Jinja2==2.7.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
PyYAML==3.10
Pygments==1.6
South==0.7.3
Sphinx==1.0.7
Twisted==10.0.0
amqplib==1.0.2
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
billiard==0.3.1
carrot==0.10.4
celery==1.0.6
coverage==3.7.1
decorator==3.4.0
distribute==0.6.24
django-nose==1.2
django-picklefield==0.3.1
django-piston==0.2.2.1
docutils==0.11
iso8601==0.1.4
meld3==0.6.10
nose==1.3.0
oauth==1.0.1
psycopg2==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.12
pycurl==7.19.5
pystache==0.3.1
python-dateutil==2.2
python-foneworx==0.1
-e git://github.com/dmaclay/python-smpp.git@4b37d211ea38f52ae282a469e377baabbcd17199#egg=python_smpp-dev
python-ssmi==0.0.6
simplejson==3.3.2
six==1.5.2
smn-alexandria==0.1.1
supervisor==3.0
-e git://github.com/dustin/twitty-twister@8524750ee73adb57bbe14ef0cfd8aa08e1e59fb3#egg=twittytwister-dev
txAMQP==0.6.2
wokkel==0.7.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
yolk==0.4.3
zope.interface
```

After running `pip install -r requirements.pip`, packages got installed one by one, installed `generator_tools` too (while it is not mentioned in the requirements, probably as dependency?), then I encountered an error saying

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/.../virtual_env/my_ve/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pt2wZL/generator-tools/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pt2wZL/generator-tools/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-pt2wZL/generator-tools/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pt2wZL/generator-tools/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-pt2wZL/generator-tools/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        assert py_version_s in ("2.5", "2.6"), "Python version 2.5 or 2.6 required"
    AssertionError: Python version 2.5 or 2.6 required
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Retried times & times, with different virtualenv, or by forcing reinstall, ... but the issue is still persisting. Earnestly searched on google but no related issue found.

Does anyone have experience on this or know what would be the solution ? Thnx

Comment: apparently, at the end of the installation, pip calls `setuptools`, and this last calls `generator_tools`.

Comment: Install [`pipdeptree`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pipdeptree) and use it to find out what package brought `generator_tools`; it is so outdated. Some of your dependencies are completely out of time.